# IOException при старте новой активности

Tags: android, activity, kotlin

Всем привет, я пытаюсь из класса, предоставляющего Fragment сделать переход на новую активность, вот так:

```
class ListScreenFragment  :android.support.v4.app.Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_activity, container, false)

        val gi=arguments!!.getSerializable("groupitem")as GroupItem



        val listLayout=view.findViewById<ViewGroup>(R.id.list_container)

        for(group in gi.groups){

            val to_add:View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_item_layout,listLayout,false)
            to_add.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.group_item_title).text=group.groupName
            to_add.setOnClickListener({
                val bundle = Bundle()
                bundle.putSerializable("groupitem", group)
                val initialFragment: Fragment = ListScreenFragment()
                initialFragment.arguments = bundle
                val manager = activity?.supportFragmentManager
                val fragmentTransaction = manager?.beginTransaction()
                fragmentTransaction?.replace(R.id.content_fragment, initialFragment)

                fragmentTransaction?.commit()
            })

            listLayout.addView(to_add)



        }
        for(entry in gi.entries){
            val to_add:View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.entry_item_layout,listLayout,false)
            to_add.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.entry_title).text=entry.lable
            to_add.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.entry_url).text=entry.url
            to_add.setOnClickListener({
               openEntry()
            })
            listLayout.addView(to_add)
        }
        return view
    }
    fun openEntry(){


        val intent = Intent(getContext(), EntryActivity::class.java)

        getContext()?.startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

Функция openEntry как раз занимается этой задачей

Переход происходит вот на эту активность:

```
class EntryActivity :AppCompatActivity(){

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        setContentView(R.layout.entry_activity)

    }
}
```

Переход уже происходит, отображается экран этой активности, как вдруг вылетает вот это исключение:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.example.kocmuk.swiftkeepass_ultimate2.Model.GroupItem)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1527)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1475)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(FragmentState.java:123)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1307)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:619)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1496)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1402)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408)
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3668)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3793)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6139)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.example.kocmuk.swiftkeepass_ultimate2.Model.EntryItem
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1224)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
        at java.util.LinkedList.writeObject(LinkedList.java:1132)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeWriteObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:977)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1536)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1472)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1218)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1584)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1549)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1472)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1218)
        at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:346)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1522)
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1475) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408) 
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentState.writeToParcel(FragmentState.java:123) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeTypedArray(Parcel.java:1307) 
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerState.writeToParcel(FragmentManager.java:619) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1496) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1402) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:724) 
        at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408) 
        at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1157) 
        at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:764) 
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.activityStopped(ActivityManagerNative.java:3668) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$StopInfo.run(ActivityThread.java:3793) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:159) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6139) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Не могу вообще понять, причем тут EntryItem и почему он должен быть Serializable, но на всякий случай вставлю и его код

```
class EntryItem constructor(var lable: String, var url: String, var username: String, var password: String, var icon: Array<ByteArray>?, var parrent: Group?) {


}
```

Вопрос: почему выпадает это исключение и как его избежать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кажется я нашел решение. При помощи Bundle я передавал в Fragment собственный объект GroupItem. Для этого мне пришлось сделать его Serializable. Однако сам GroupItem содержал массив из EntryItem и другие объекты, которые не являлись Serializable. Вот кстати мой класс GroupItem:

```
class GroupItem : Serializable {

    var groupName:String?=""
    @Transient
    var group:Group?=null

    var groups=LinkedList<GroupItem>()
    @Transient
    var entries=LinkedList<EntryItem>()
}
```

В нем я отметил все переменные классов, которые не являются Serializable аннотацией @Transient, после чего все заработало. Если кому интересно, вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245600/what-does-the-keyword-transient-mean-in-java) рассказывается про эту аннотацию.